# Alternative of browserLocation in angularjs-2.0

Tags: angular

previously we used  browserLocation.path(); to get current url of web page but it is not available in beta version of angularjs 2.0
What is the alternative of browserLocation and how can we get current url path with query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject [Location](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Location-class.html) like

```
constuctor(private location: Location) {
  console.log(location.path());
}
```

Comment: I need browser current path to load a dynamic template, in @View .. How can I do that? One solution is to use windows.location.href....       [code] @View({
        
        templateUrl: (function ( ) { 
      
            var location = window.location.href;
       return location.replace('manage', 'manageinner');
        }() ) [code]

Comment: I don't know if dynamic template is even supported currently in Angular2. What path do you get from `location.path()` and what would you need. Can you post a concrete path example?

Comment: yes dynamic template is supported, currently it is working with above code in comment which I have given ....

Comment: Oh, saw the comment before it was completed. Ok, this only works in TS but not in Dart which I'm using. Doesn't look like you can use DI for code in annotations. Sorry, I don't know a solution for this specific case.